# SQL syntax error near 'fieldname'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am fairly new to C# i have a database which i need fill with windows forms, the button that inserts data into the table has the following code:

```
private void btnAddEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=.\\server1; database = PMS; Integrated security=true;");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tblEmployees cid, empID, empFirstName, empMidName, "
                +"empLastName, empAge, empTitle, empAddress, empRank, empSalary, empEmail, empPhone, "
                +"empMobile, Notes, userName, usrPassword, usrAccessLevel, empActive, empMarked, empType "
                +"VALUES ('" + this.txtID + "', '" + this.txtEmpID + "', '" + this.txtFirstName + "','" + this.txtMidName + "'," +
                " '" + this.txtLastName + "', '" + this.txtEmpAge + "', '" + this.txtJobTitle + "', '" + this.txtAddress + "', " +
                " '" + this.cmbRank + "', '" + this.txtSalary + "', '" + this.txtEmail + "', '" + this.txtPhone + "', " + 
                " '" + this.txtMobile + "', '" + this.txtNote + "', '" + this.txtUserName + "', '" + this.txtPassword + "', " + 
                " '" + this.cmbAcsLevel + "', '" + this.txtActive + "', '" + this.txtMarked + "', '" + this.txtType + "')", cn);

        if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        object o = da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

however after clicking the button i get the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'cid'.'

Comment: Missing brackets around field names. It should be `INSERT INTO tblEmployees (cid,..... empType )`

Comment: Also, read about SQL injection and how to prevent it using parameterised queries. Your code is horribly insecure.

Comment: And even with forms apps, you should practice safety and use *parameters* to keep SQL *code* and *data* separate, rather than mangling them together by string manipulation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Also consider not storing numeric data as strings (e.g. salary). Also consider storing date of birth, rather than Age (since Age keeps changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make it simple and use [Parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) to prevent [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

```
     using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=.\\server1; database = PMS; Integrated security=true;"))
      {
     String query = "INSERT INTO tblEmployees (cid, empID, empFirstName, empMidName,empLastName, empAge, empTitle, empAddress, empRank, empSalary, empEmail, empPhone,empMobile, Notes, userName, usrPassword, usrAccessLevel, empActive, empMarked, empType) VALUES (@cid, @empID, @empFirstName, @empMidName,@empLastName, @empAge, @empTitle, @empAddress, @empRank, @empSalary, @empEmail, @empPhone,@empMobile, @Notes, @userName, @usrPassword, @usrAccessLevel, @empActive, @empMarked, @empType)";

using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @empFirstName", empFirstName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empMidName", empMidName);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empLastName", empLastName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empAge", empAge);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @empTitle", empTitle);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empAddress", empAddress);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empRank", empRank);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empSalary", empSalary);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @empEmail", empEmail);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empPhone", empPhone);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empMobile", empMobile);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrPassword", usrPassword);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrAccessLevel", usrAccessLevel);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empActive", empActive);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empMarked", empMarked);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empType", empType);
     connection.Open();
      int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Check Error
       if(result < 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, however it gives me an error like: System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.'

Comment: @Khalid what is the error show me

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.'

Comment: you just need to verify that all the values on the right hand side are valid see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543635/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-windows-forms-datetimepicker-to-a-know

Comment: just check with all values

Answer (score 0):

@trailmax is right -- for SQL you would need parentheses around the list of column names, to separate them from the "INSERT INTO " and "VALUES" parts which come before and after, like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblEmployees (cid, empID, empFirstName, empMidName,empLastName, empAge, empTitle, empAddress, empRank, empSalary, empEmail, empPhone,empMobile, Notes, userName, usrPassword, usrAccessLevel, empActive, empMarked, empType) VALUES (
[...]
```

Answer (score -4):

I find it is easy to debug code like this by creating a string for the query using string.format.  The you can take the string results and put into SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which has much better diagnostics to help find issue.

```
            string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO tblEmployees cid, empID, empFirstName, empMidName, " +
                           "empLastName, empAge, empTitle, empAddress, empRank, empSalary, empEmail, empPhone, " +
                           "empMobile, Notes, userName, usrPassword, usrAccessLevel, empActive, empMarked, empType " +
                           "VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}'," +
                                   "'{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}','{19}')",
                                   this.txtID, this.txtEmpID, this.txtFirstName, this.txtMidName, this.txtLastName,
                                   this.txtEmpAge, this.txtJobTitle, this.txtAddress, this.cmbRank, this.txtSalary,
                                   this.txtEmail, this.txtPhone, this.txtMobile, this.txtNote, this.txtUserName,
                                   this.txtPassword, this.cmbAcsLevel, this.txtActive, this.txtMarked, this.txtType);
```

Comment: Perhaps a good tip, but IMO this is by no means an answer to the question.

Comment: My code probably solves the issue since you can easily see all the commas and single quotes are in the correct locations.

Comment: This is still susceptible to Sql Injection, however.  Better to use parameters and get the best of both worlds!